# Erro ao enviar app para a apple store - Invalid Image Path

Tags: ios, apache-cordova, ionic

Ao tentar fazer o upload da aplicação para a apple store esta me apresentando o seguinte erro e não consegui identificar como resolver esse erro.

Nessa aplicação estou usando o ionic, anteriormente eu já havia enviado essa mesma aplicação para a loja sem problemas, mais após um update está me apresentando o erro abaixo!!! Alguma dica?? Obrigado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou esta resposta (Ingles): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165916/error-itms-90032invalid-image-path-no-image-found-at-the-path-referenced-und

Comment: Acabei encontrando como resolver esse problema... https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/commit/4ca3f28bae30b0974da7a7a4033d158b08303c4c?diff=unified

Comment: Para ajudar outras pessoas, recomendo que responda sua própria pergunta com esta solução, procure detalhar a resposta, não utilize somente link para justificar.

Answer (score 0):

No arquivo '**PROJECT_NAME**-Info.plist' Identifique e remova as seguintes linhas;

```
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>icon.png</string>
```

Isso corrige o erro submissão ITC que este arquivo está faltando.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/commit/4ca3f28bae30b0974da7a7a4033d158b08303c4c?diff=unified