# Erro para publicar aplicativo na Apple - xCode

Tags: ios, apache-cordova, xcode, apple

Galera, estou tentando publicar um aplicativo na apple desenvolvido com o Cordova, na hora que tento fazer o envio do aplicativo usando o xCode 7 aparece este erro aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já rodei o google em uma solução, mas nao tive sucesso, encontrei várias dicas mas tudo que falaram eu fiz e nao consegui.

Alguem ja passou por isso ou tem uma solução?

Comment: No contexto do Cordova não sei; no contexto do projeto XCode, provavelmente falta adicionar o arquivo icon.png no projeto. Veja se o arquivo consta na seção Build Phases, item Copy Bundle Resources da config do projeto.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113297/erro-ao-enviar-app-para-a-apple-store-invalid-image-path

Comment: Opa, me ajudou muito obrigadooo.. ja tava ficando louco!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erro ao enviar app para a apple store - Invalid Image Path](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113297/erro-ao-enviar-app-para-a-apple-store-invalid-image-path)